# Javascript else if statement stops executing unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is my first question to the community here so please forgive any shortcomings with respect to best practices.

I have a JavaScript else if statement which stops executing immediately after the following snippet of the else if statement:

```
} else if (email != '') {
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        email = email.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

I have tried removing the nested if statement completely and logging a message to the console to make sure that when the condition of the else if statement is being met I can very in the console. For example, the output to the console in this case is "email has a value"

```
} else if (email != '') {
        console.log('email has a value');
    }
```

After that the else if statement seems to stop executing. I'm really hung up here and any guidance is greatly appreciated - thank you in advance.

Following is the comprehensive set of pertinent code if that is helpful to provide some context:

```
function applyFocus(target, message) {
    alert(message);
    document.getElementById(target).focus();
}

function validateEmail(mail) {
    var mailLower = mail.toLowerCase();
    if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(mailLower)) {
        console.log('returning true');
        return true;
    } else {
        errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
        applyFocus('email', errorMessage);
        console.log('returning false');
        return false;
    }

if (firstName == '') {
    // do something
 } else if (lastName == '') {
    // do something
 } else if (email == '') {
    // do something
 } else if (email != '') {
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        email = email.toLowerCase();
    }
 } else if (industry == '') {
    // do something
 } else {
     // do something
 }
```

Comment: What are you wanting to run after? There isn't any more code after that.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that once a condition is satisfied, it will stop running the nested if/else's

Comment: also your condition is redundant

Comment: Please add ALL the relevant code so that we can replicate your issue. That means HTML as well.

Comment: you forgot to close your function

Comment: Just a note that you can evaluate multiple expressions at once. You don't need the second if statement inside your `else if`. For example: `else if (email != '' && validateEmail(email)) { //do stuff }`

Comment: what is happening in section `// do something`? do yiu want to show only one error/missing input or all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the very first (else) if block, whose condition is met, will be executed.

For example:

```
var a = something;
if (a == '') {
 // Block A
}
else if (a != '') {
  // Block B
}
else if (another condition) {
 // Block C
}
```

Block C will never be executed, because one of the previous conditions will always be satisified. It doesn't check anything after that. What you most likely want is something like:

```
 if (firstName == '') {
    // do something
 }

 if (lastName == '') {
    // do something
 } 

 if (email == '') {
    // do something
 } else {
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        email = email.toLowerCase();
    }
 }

 if (industry == '') {
    // do something
 } else {
     // do something
 }
```

Comment: This approach turned out to be the solution for my application. Thank you @user2953241 (and everyone) for the insight and guidance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the second `else if` condition is not satisfied, then the third one automatically is, therefore the ones after it will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach and *return early* if one condition is met.

```
function check() {
    if (firstName === '') {
        // do something
        return;
    }

    if (lastName === '') {
        // do something
        return;
    }

    email = email.toLowerCase();
    if (email === '' || !validateEmail(email)) {
        // do something
        return;
    } 

    if (industry == '') {
        // do something
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nina. Using the return approach at each conditional was key to my success here.

Answer (score 0):

If it's of benefit, below is the final JS that works well for my application. It's a straightforward client side validation of an HTML form with email regex validation. Hope this is helpful for someone out there:

```
// BEGIN form handling //

function validateForm(e) {

    // Prevent anchor default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Collect form data
    var firstName = '';
    firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lastName = '';
    lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var email = '';
    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    email = email.toLowerCase();
    var phoneNumber = '';
    phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
    var companyName = '';
    companyName = document.getElementById('companyName').value;
    var industry = '';
    industry = document.getElementById('industry').value;

    // Create json array to store form data
    var data = {
        firstName : firstName,
        lastName : lastName,
        email : email,
        phoneNumber : phoneNumber,
        companyName : companyName,
        industry : industry
     }

    //error handling
    //alert error, highlight border of form element, add focus
    function applyFocus(target, message) {
        alert(message);
        document.getElementById(target).focus();
    }

    // reset form
    function resetForm() {
        document.getElementById('letsTalkForm').reset();
     }

     // redirect to homepage
    function goHome() {
        window.location.href = './';
    }

    // Send form data via ajax - post request to SMS
    function submitToSMS(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "REDACTED", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //stringify for AWS lambda
        var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
        //xhttp.send(data);
        xhttp.send(payload);
        console.log('the payload for lambda is: ' + payload);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log('success');
                // alert sender of successful send
                alert('Thank you for contacting Motiv - We look forward to speaking with you!');
                // clear form fields
                resetForm();
                // redirect to homepage
                goHome();
            } else if (this.readyState == 1) {
                console.log('server connection established');
            } else if (this.readyState == 2) {
                console.log('request received');
            } else if (this.readyState == 3) {
                console.log('processing request');
            } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                console.log('request finished and response ready');
            } else {
                console.log('something went wrong');
            }
        }
    }

    // Validate form data
    var errorMessage = '';

     if (firstName == '') {
        errorMessage = 'Please let us know your First Name.';
        applyFocus('firstName', errorMessage);
        return false
     } 
     if (lastName == '') {
        errorMessage = 'Please let us know your Last Name.';
        applyFocus('lastName', errorMessage);
        return false
     }
     if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)) {
        console.log('returning true with value: ' + email);
     } else {
        errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
        applyFocus('email', errorMessage);
        return false;
     }
     if (industry == '') {
        errorMessage = 'Please let us know your Industry.';
        applyFocus('industry', errorMessage);
     } else {
         console.log ('the value of errorMessage is: ' + errorMessage);
         // submit form data to SMS
         submitToSMS();
         // log data array to console
         console.log(data);
         // Clear form
     }
}

// END form handling //
```